# Iframe in Chrome dont show images

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I call an external page into a iframe, In mozilla firefox runs fine but Google Chrome doest show images

example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgemorgado25/m1xugp3y/2/

```
<iframe
src="https://flixe.streann.com/live/" 
width="100%" height="400" 
scrolling="yes"
frameborder=0>
```

Comment: Open the Developer Tools with the F12 key, reload the page.  What are the warnings and/or errors in the console?

Comment: There is an error Uncaught Error: No options detected. Please consult documentation.
    at SmartBanner.publish (smartbanner.js:412)
    at smartbanner.js:114......   But is appears in original site too